# How check if there is any turtle ahead of this turtle

Tags: simulation, netlogo, turtle-graphics

i am new to netlogo, and i would like to have a "falling in line" to pay in grocery simulation. but my problem is turtles are overlapping itself instead of falling in line. i would like to check if there is any turtle ahead, if true then that turtle will stop.

Comment: Nice try, but it's turtles all the way down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for the `turtles-on` primitive](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-on) has an example of doing something like this:

```
ask turtles [
  if not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    [ fd 1 ]
]
```

You can vary the distance used with [`patch-ahead`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-ahead), but if you choose something less than 1, you'll need to check for [`other`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other) turtles only:

```
if not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 0.5
```

Comment: i keep digging that documentation but i never expect that turtles-on is the right one to use. thanks for this tho